# How to list html elements of a given class in order of occurrence?

Tags: jquery

I have a one page html file structured like this:

```
<div id="foo" class="segment">
    Foo content
</div>
 <div id="bar" class="segment">
    Bar content
</div>
... etc ...
```

I want to use jQuery to create a nav bar with buttons in the same order, e.g.

```
<button id="Navfoo" class="nav">Foo</button>
<button id="Navbar" class="nav">Bar</button>
```

Being a big believer in the DRY principle, (Don't Repeat Yourself) I'd like to create the Nav buttons programmatically to make the page easier to maintain when segments are added, deleted, or re-ordered.  It's easy enough to get an iterator over the segment divs with

```
$(".segment")
```

but how can I ensure the iteration will be in the same order the elements appear on the page?

Comment: Currently, the buttons are hard-coded. I haven't found anything that says what order jquery selectors are returned.  I posted the question because I don't want to waste a lot of time trying to do something unsupported.

Comment: They are in same order as in the DOM from top. jquery object is an array-like object so order is preserved

Comment: have a look at [.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Comment: Excellent. Thanks, roasted! If that works as expected, how do I accept your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the .segments and build your buttons, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/U6MHA/

```
<div id="foo" class="segment">
    Foo content
</div>
 <div id="bar" class="segment">
    Bar content
</div>
<div id="result" />


var segments = $('.segment');
var buttons = $.map(segments, function(a)
                    { 
                        var id = $(a).attr('id');
                        return '<button id="' + id + '" class="nav">' + id + '</button>'; 
                    }).join('<br />');

segments.detach();
$('#result').html(buttons);
```

Comment: Thanks and +1 for the $.map.  I didn't know jQuery had that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".segment").each(function(){
    // create nav items
});
```

With this method it will follow the DOM order

Comment: even `$(".segment")` will follow the DOM, i mean each() will follow order returned by the matched set of elements